# Can I specify operating system with a node definition in Puppet?

Tags: linux, puppet, operating-system

I want to do something along the lines of:

[image]

Is this possible with Puppet? If not, what's the best way I can distinguish modules by operating system?

Comment: To whoever downvoted, please explain why. If this is not possible with a node definition, is there another way to do this?

Comment: Probably down voted because there are details you haven't posted, or the DV doesn't understand the question.
Short answer: Yes, it is possible. Are you using Puppet Enterprise? Puppet Open source (free version)? Foreman?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the answer you are looking for is `$::osfamily`
Will a case command work for your instance?

```
case $::osfamily {
  'Debian', 'Suse': {
       ...stuff for Deb/Suse...
   }
   'RedHat': {
        ...stuff for RH ...
    }
    'Windows': {
        ...stuff for Windows...
    }
    Default: {
        ... default stuff ...
    }
} # -- End Case
```

To see what else is available, at a command prompt run:
`facter os`

You can run `facter` with no arguments, send it to a file and peruse all the *facts* that puppet knows.

Comment: This worked really well, thank you!

Comment: You're Welcome. Glad to hear it worked for you!